# Why aren't my CSS grid layout divs centered on large viewports?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to display div inside a parent div but want the children divs to be in the centre and not from the beginning of the parent div. The HTML/CSS is given below along with a screenshot of how it looks on iPad (seems alright) and computer(not something I want).

```css
.inner-tile {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr ));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  justify-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.event {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-width: 240px;
  min-height: 270px;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class = "inner-tile">
    <div class = "event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href = "#learnmore" class = "learn-more">event</a>
    </div>          
    <div class = "event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href = "#learnmore" class = "learn-more">event</a>
    </div>          
    <div class = "event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href = "#learnmore" class = "learn-more">event</a>
    </div>          
    <div class = "event">
      <div class="event-image"></div>
      <a href = "#learnmore" class = "learn-more">event</a>
    </div>          
  </div>
```

[image: iPad]

[image: Desktop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will always have 4 items you can conside `max-width` and use `grid` instead of `inline-grid` then you can center using margin auto

```css
.inner-tile {
  display: grid;
  max-width: calc(240px * 4 + 5px * 3);
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  justify-items: center;
  
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.event {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-width: 240px; 
  min-height: 270px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-tile">
  <div class="event">
    <div class="event-image"></div>
    <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">event</a>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="event-image"></div>
    <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">event</a>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="event-image"></div>
    <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">event</a>
  </div>
  <div class="event">
    <div class="event-image"></div>
    <a href="#learnmore" class="learn-more">event</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer works but i wanna know why justify-items: center isn't doing what i want

Comment: justify-items is used to center the items inside the grid (as its name) not to center the grid itself.

Comment: isn't the divs inside the parent div children of the parents div.

Comment: @Syed.bcc yes they are, and in the grid context those childs are called grid items and the parent a grid container. Justify-items is used to center the items inside the container

Comment: yes and so that's what i want to achieve, the parent div is already taking full width (see the border) and i want to display the items in the centre of the parent div.

Comment: @Syed.bcc you are using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr))` so this will create columns with 240px width at least and when your element is full width you will have empty columns and the first 4 items are centred inside their columns. Inspect the element to notice the empty columns

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   justify-items: center;
```

for more see https://alligator.io/css/align-justify/

Comment: the number of columns are not always the same. I need to render 1 at a time when browsing on mobile.

Answer (score -1):

Use `justify-content: center;`css code instead of `justify-items: center;` for outer div

Comment: can you share example code so I can work on it to resolve this issue?